# how to run model training using feature store databricks api

Tags: databricks, mlops

to execute model training using databricks feature store api.

Performed using UI, Any best way apart from using databricks UI.

Best possible solution to run experimentation from databricks api.

Model training using api + feature table creation using feature store api.